# What is the symbolic meaning behind Lord Shiva sitting in snow clad mountain Kailasa?

Tags: shiva, symbolism

We often see lot of pictures of Lord Shiva sitting in the snow clad mountain of Kailasa.

Does it represent anything symbolically?

P.S. I'm not interested in the story of how Shiva came to live on Mount Kailasa.

Comment: Are you asking how Shiva started living on Mount Kailash?

Comment: No , what Kailash symbolically represents....

Comment: Maybe because Shiva is said meditate sitting in Mount Kailash which is covered in snow? Lets see if anyone has answers :)

Comment: @KiranRS OK, then you should edit your question to make that clear.  Because your question title makes it sound as if you want the mythological story of how Shiva came to live on Mount Kailash.  But in any case, the suggestion that Shiva living on mount Kailash is a symbolic thing is somewhat controversial.  A lot of traditional Hindus, myself included believe that he literally lives on Mount Kailash.

Comment: @KiranRS So it's an odd question to ask what his living there symbolizes.  It's like asking what Rama being born in Ayodhya symbolizes.

Comment: I found the story of how Shiva came to Kailash, if you're interested.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan please share :)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan 
 - it is not a normal thing as any avathar born in some place... Because they live a normal humans life unlike trinities. Trinities didn't move to another place permanently, and never had a normal human beings life including avathars. Got you what  i mean? :)

Comment: One representation sir - The snow clad mountain Kailasha represents the purest Heart. Snow is white, the mountains are known for their pure and serene environment, secluded from the worldly mallice. Lord Shiva, who is Parabrahman, who is God, resides in the purest Heart. The Heart where purity reigns is Kailasha or the Dwelling place of Parameshwar :). All the best!!

Comment: @KiranRS: I can answer this question i.e. the symbolism behind it. I wonder why it has not been reopened yet?

Comment: @KiranRS What do you mean by "What is the mythology behind..." - do you want the actual story or just the symbolic meaning? If you don't care about the actual story, then, you should use symbolism tag and make it clear in your question - this way it has a good chance of getting reopened. You used mythology tag which means you want the story behind it and you also say "what does it represent" - seems like you want both of them?

Comment: @KiranRS You need to make it clear what you want in the question itself, not in the comments. I suggest you edit it this way: **1.** How did Shiva come to live on Mount Kailash, what is the story? **2.** Is there also a symbolic meaning to it?

Comment: @sv - My question is very very clear as per your comment.Look at once agian. :-)

Comment: @KiranRS I actually edited your question after reading your earlier comments to make it clear. Then your question was reopened :)

Answer (score 2):

The symbolic meaning behind Kailasa is that it represents celebration. Also, it is interesting to note that Shiva also said to reside in the Smashana:

> The abode of Shiva is in Mount Kailasa, and the *smashana* (the
>   cremation ground). *Kailasa* means 'where there is only celebration',
>   and *smashana* is where there is only void. The Divinity dwells in the
>   void as well as in celebration. And in you there is void, in you there
>   is celebration.

An explanation from an article by Sri Sri Ravi Shankar:

https://xa.yimg.com/kq/groups/17184919/1536824014/name/understandingshiva.pdf

Comment: Good but not satisfactory :}

Comment: @TheDestroyer: Well, as long as the OP is satisfied :P Also, I could add etymological meanings, that might provide more insights?

Comment: What does "Shiva sitting on Kailash" mean? This is what OP wants. So, you may need to edit your answer according to that.

Comment: @TheDestroyer That is what is means : Divinity (Shiva) is found in celebration (Kailasa)

Comment: You should mention Divinity and void as Shiva in your answer to make things clear.

Comment: @sv.: Oh, my mistake, it was written as sma only, I thought it was a typing mistake and changed it. Lemme edit.

Answer (score 2):

Lord Shiva is symbolically represented as dwelling in Mount Kailash because he is said to be too iridescent, vivacious and fiery. The mountain's cool and serene environment and the goddess Ganga on his matted locks atone for his fiery nature. (Although Goddess Ganga flows from his locks for an another reason). Being the supreme lord, he is ever absorbed in meditation on himself to regulate the cosmos.

Comment: Please cite sources.